# Distinct left cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be group $G_{14}$ of invertible congruence classes modulo $14$. Write down the distinct left cosets of subgroup $H = \{[1]_{14},[13]_{14}\}$.

I know $3H=\{[3]_{14},[11]_{14}\}$ and $5H=\{[5]_{14},[9]_{14}\}$. What I don't understand is why we should choose only $3H$ and $5H$?

Comment: The group in question has $6$ elements; thus when you get to $6$ elements you are done

Comment: FYI, there's no need to refer to *left* cosets, as the group is clearly abelian.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, that group is denoted $U(14)$ or $(\Bbb Z_{14})^{\times}$  and has order $\phi(14) = \phi(7) = 6$, with:

$U(14) = \{[1]_{14},[3]_{14},[5]_{14},[9]_{14},[11]_{14},[13]_{14}\}$

Since $|H| = 2$, the number of cosets is $\dfrac{6}{2} = 3$.

Explicitly, these are:

$H = \{[1]_{14},[13]_{14}\} = 13H$

$3H = \{[3]_{14}, [11]_{14}\} = 11H$

$5H = \{[5]_{14}, [9]_{14}\} = 9H$.

As you can see, we have no more elements of $U(14)$ to put in a different coset.

Comment: How do you get U(14)={1,3,5,9,11,13}?

Comment: @NikAhmadIrfan An integer $n$ has an inverse mod $14$ if and only if $\operatorname{gcd}(n, 14) = 1$, i.e. $n$ and $14$ are relatively prime. You can check that the numbers satisfying this condition are the ones listed.